# UpgradeData.php script is not Working

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I want to remove some new category attributes but it is not working. 
Am I missing something? I dont know what is the problem. Please someone help it..

UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;

    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') > 0){

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'category_title');
        }
        $setup->endSetup();

    }

}
```

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.5">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

**module.xml**  `module.xml` and not `Module.xml`

```
...
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.5">
...
```

**UpgradeData.php**

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.5', '<')) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your version check **if** logic

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0){
```

[Check here how magento use that compare](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php#L74)

Make sure your module.xml version is **'1.0.6'**